# Files are being transferred to FTP server from my system but not from Windows server

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, windows-server-2012

I have developed a utility to transfer .csv files from Windows Server to FTPs server through Task Scheduler. It had been working just fine up until now. But now it is returning following error

> System.Net.WebException Message : Unable to connect to the remote
> server StackTrace :    at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()

However, when I transfer the same files with same credentials from my machine, the transfer succeeds. Please help me find out what's wrong and help me resolve it.

Comment: I assume: firewall changes?

Comment: @Llama. Okay. Our infrastructure is a different section. What specifically do I ask them?

Comment: "Why can't this server do FTP to that server?"

Comment: This is not really a programming problem, its more a basic computer, life skills and problem solving issue. The short of this is the error speaks for itself and something has changed in your environment or code... What that is or could be, we don't know